# Rails - Show which client a project belongs to in the project index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, belongs-to

A client `has_many` projects. A project `belongs_to` a client.

How do I show in the index view, inside the `@projects` loop, which client that project belongs to?

This is what I'm trying to do in the view:

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
   <% project.client.name %>
<% end %>
```

Here's all I have in the projects controller & I think this is where I'm stuck:

```
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @project = Project.new
    @clients = Client.select("DISTINCT name, id")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @projects }
    end
  end
```

I got this working with a HABTM relationship, but I'm trying to do it w/ a has_many belongs_to relationship now instead.

Comment: you've missed the `=` out of `<%= project.client.name %>`

Comment: By the way, try to make as few instance variables in controller actions as possible. One, ideally. It's a better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
   <% project.client.name %>
<% end %>
```

with

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
   <%= project.client.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Duh, can't believe I missed that. Thanks :)